# client_credentials oauth2 token from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Is it possible to get an oauth2 token from Azure DevOps using `client_credentials`?

I'm POSTing the following payload:

```
client_id={clientID}&
client_secret={clientSecret}&
grant_type=client_credentials
```

With a `content_type` header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And calling `https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token`

But that call is returning an error http 400

Comment: Thanks for the edits @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

The only document of OAuth2 flow for Azure devops available in Microsoft sites is [OAuth2 authorization code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops).

You can go [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report this problem to Miscrosoft Develop team. Click **Report a problem** and select **Azure Devops**

[image]

Comment: are you certain? The link you provided shows how to do a authorization code grant flow but doesn't say that client_credentials are not supported. Comments in the library suggest they are supported. Specifically, the Summary of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.OAuth.VssOAuthGrantType enum states "Lists the supported authorization grant types" and an item in the enum is "ClientCredentials = 1"

Comment: There is a lack of document about client_credentials grant flow. You can create a ticket  [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report this issue to Micrsoft Development team, Hopely they will check about this issue and provide a fix.

Comment: This issue has been raised to Microsoft by other users, you can follow them and join in the discussion [in this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/540283/support-for-client-credentials-msi-authorization-a.html) or this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/731367/custom-service-endpoint-authentication-with-oauth.html)